# How to call a specific javascript function into html?

Tags: javascript, html

as mentioned in the title I need a specific javascript function to be called in html, the function changes constantly upon pressing start and it looks the following:

```
<dt style="width: 120px">Start 1:</dt> <dd style="margin-left: 150px">{{ start.number1 }}</dd>
```

{{ start.number1 }} is the function I need to be displayed in html, could you help me with that please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't just have the results of a javascript function appear in html, you need to add some code in javacript which will insert the required test or html elements in the right place. If you show your current js code you may get some useful suggestions about how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Using curly brackets to bind a Javascript variable into your HTML view is something very typical of javascript frameworks that provide [Data Binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UI_data_binding) such as [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) or [EmberJS](http://emberjs.com/)
This might be what you're looking for.

There are of course other ways of doing this, such as the new [Object.observe()](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es7/observe/) function that's available in Chrome, but it will take a while until its widely supported.